# Firefox keypress Event with Ctrl

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developing a firefox addon.
When trying to capture the keypress event I can see the output for it on my browser console.
But not if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> for example:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function ()  {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }, true);
}, false);
```

Output when pressing tab only:

```
keypress { target: <body.ask-page.new-topbar>, key: "Tab", charCode: 0, keyCode: 9 }
```

Why keypress doesn't triggers on any Ctrl combination?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't trigger, but you can use `keyup`. If you use `keydown` you will have to ignore repeat sends. as while they hold it down it repeatedly sends keydown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close this question: Here's my bug report including the fix which is the reason keypress don't get fired if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> combination is pressed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1068282

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment im not sure why `e.ctlrKey` isn't true on `keypress`.

What you can try `getModifierState`

```
window.addEventListener('load', function ()  {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
        console.error('Control down:', e.getModifierState('Control'));
    }, true);
}, false);
```

[MDN :: getModifierState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.getModifierState)

## edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/ace4tuwo/

shows you can do this in keypress with getmodifier. works as long as you use ctrl as a modifier, meaning you press and hold ctrl first

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough: There's no output when pressing Ctrl + any other key. There's only an output without Ctrl key. It seems keypress doesn't triggers.

Comment: Oh I see, you are adding it to document, try adding to window, if that still doesn't work, then switch to using `keyup` or switch to `keydown`. Make sure to check `e.repeat == false`

Comment: Same result: No output. I don't want to use keyup/keydown as there's keypress and it worked till a specific firefox version (I just don't know which version exactly). But some day it stopped working.

Comment: File a bug a at bugzilla, they help you find out if it really did stop working after a certain version.

Comment: Maybe this is related to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=968056 and I really need to use keydown in combination with e.repeat. But that would be a really dirty solution cause I need to look for Ctrl+Tab and need to use a boolean flag then to set if ctrl was clicked or not.

Comment: Yes boolean is the way to go. You can just check `e.ctrlKey`. But make sure to check `e.repeat` keydown fires multi times